# use createHash in angular-md5

Tags: angularjs

When I wanna use the createHash function in angular, this error raises : `md5.createHash is not a function`

Here's my code :

```
MyCtrl.$inject = ['md5'];
function MyCtrl(md5) {
var vm = this;

vm.reg = reg;

function reg() {
    vm.avatar = md5.createHash('salam'); // This Line Has Error
    console.log(vm.avatar);
...
```

Note: I added the module dependency fine !

Comment: I m getting the same error what did you do to remove this error ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add angular-md5 to your project module as well le below.

```
angular.module('YOUR_APP', [
    'angular-md5', // you may also use 'ngMd5' or 'gdi2290.md5' 
    'controllers'
  ]);
```

Comment: As I said , I did it well !

Comment: can you post the error message you are getting. everything else is looking good

Comment: I said it in the first post :
md5.createHash is not a function

Comment: Here I've done a working example https://plnkr.co/edit/bCGVvfkVIATC1HS2VIbL?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

**Not sure what happened, but you might be able to backtrack from a fiddle I made you**

```html
<body ng-app="YOUR_APP" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{ email | gravatar }}.jpg?d=identicon">
  <input type="text" ng-model="email" placeholder="Message Here"> {{ message }}
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-md5/0.1.10/angular-md5.js"></script>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('YOUR_APP', [
    'angular-md5', // you may also use 'ngMd5' or 'gdi2290.md5' 
  ]).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, md5) {

    $scope.$watch('email', function(val) {
      $scope.message = 'Your message Hash is: ' + md5.createHash($scope.email || '');
    });

  });
</script>
```

`

Comment: I saw it in https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-md5 and then I made my codes ...

Comment: Yes, thats the code base, but i changed how the controller was defined, and how it injects rather than using a string array which is not great when uglifying your js. This is the concise way of declaring your controllers.